# Crontab not running script

Tags: cron

EDITED:

I got a script running with a cronjob every day at 1 am:

```
0 1 * * * /bin/bash /home/performanceRatio.sh
```

It also appears in the cron.log:

```
Feb  2 01:00:01 inf-education-67 CRON[108963]: (root) CMD (bash performanceRatio.sh)
Feb  2 01:00:01 inf-education-67 CRON[108962]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Expected behavior is to update a mysql database. Changes appear if it's run manually.

Using Ubuntu 20.04

My script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

python3 get_weather_data_crn.py && python3 pv.py
```

`* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output` shows:

```
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/root
```

Comment: You will likely want to use the full path to bash: `/usr/bin/bash`

Comment: @Matigo Thanks, i will try this out and respond tomorrow if it worked. Do I also have to use the full path of the file? Like /home/performanceRatio.sh ?

Comment: Yes, that would be important as well. Always use full paths for everything when working with crontab.

Comment: @Matigo All right, I'll try this out and respond to you tomorrow. Thanks so far! :)

Comment: You **will** need the full path to `performanceRatio.sh` unless it's located in the `HOME` of the user whose crontab the job is in ... you should **not** need the full path to `bash` since `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are in the default cron `PATH`. However you wouldn't need `bash` at all if you use an appropriate shebang in your script and make it executable.

Comment: Is the full path of your script `/home/performanceRatio.sh` ??

Comment: @ArturMeinild Yes, it's the full path.

Comment: And what's the path of `get_weather_data_crn.py` and `pv.py`? Are they also in `/home`? Because I can't see `/home` anywhere in your path. You need to reference full path for python scripts also.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Yes, they are in /home . Do I have to add it in performanceRatio.sh too?
Like: `python3 /home/get_weather_data_crn.py && /home/python3 pv.py`

Comment: Yes you have to.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Sadly still not working.

Comment: You made an error in the last part. It should be `python3 /home/get_weather_data_crn.py && python3 /home/pv.py`

Comment: @ArturMeinild Yea, I recognized that. I tested to run `env > /tmp/env.output` inside the sh file and it did the jib. But the Python scripts weon't run..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe it was a combination of the edits I already made (also in my post). But the final solution to get it all working was this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

python3 /home/get_weather_data_crn.py && 
python3 /home/pv.py
```

Yes, not making a NEWLINE! after && prevented Crontab to run the python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Jobs run through `cron`, `crontab`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.